# print prime number upto number N

Tags: c++14

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int N;
    cin>>N;
    int flag=1;
    for(int i=2;i<=N;i++){
        for(int j=2;j<i;j++){
            if(i%j==0){flag=0;break;}
            break;
        }
        if(flag==1){cout<<i<<" ";}
    }
    return 0;
}
```

program is to print prime numbers upto input number N with seperated space
ex - N=9, my o/p -2 3, 
expected o/p - 2 3 5 7
help

Answer (score 0):

Just initial flag = 1 after every iteration

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int N;
    cin>>N;
    int flag=1;
    for(int i=2;i<=N;i++){
    flag=1;
        for(int j=2;j<i;j++){
            if(i%j==0){flag=0;break;}
            break;
        }
        if(flag==1){cout<<i<<" ";}
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try it with an input of 9 or larger; resetting `flag` isn't enough to fix this code.

Answer (score 0):

You've got at least two issues:

1. You never reset `flag` to `1`. So as soon as a non-prime is found, everything is non-prime. You want to set it back to `1` each time you loop in the outer loop.
2. You break out of your inner loop unconditionally (`j` is never anything but `2`), so you're actually testing for "is odd" not "is prime". Only `break` if you've confirmed it's not prime.

Fix that, and the code works:

```cpp
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
     int N;
     cin>>N;
     for(int i=2;i<=N;i++){
         int flag=1; // Set each loop
         for(int j=2;j<i;j++){
             if(i%j==0){
                 flag=0;
                 break; // Only break when confirmed composite
             }
             // no break otherwise
         }
         if(flag==1){
             cout<<i<<" ";
         }
     }
     return 0;
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY9NDoMgFIT3nIK0aaIxTbSbLgCP4B0oonlW0fCzajw7BatpqmXDvJl880BM07UVwvszKNG7WlIYjdWSDyVyBlSLFR@kmbiQ2NiaIFAWDxxUkuIXwvFEpyIfLUCV5TY0o05iCOxGgLKKQJalK7SBTc9bVpCvuUFdgDoKpPtlFq5J4NIxlu@DhY@FOTkGj/Cp586f0T8Z@pcWVuwXiNFZSoHSEz6RA7teWlqnFQ5vmL2/vwE)